# Axios in Vuex Store returning promise and not data

Tags: axios, vuex

I'm not sure why I can't get the data I want from this `axios.get` in my Vuex store.

I've setup this `action` to `commit` a change to my `mutation` like this:

```js
      mutations: {
        updateShop: (state, payload ) => {
          state.shop = payload;
          return state.shop;
        }
      },
      actions: {
        getShop: ({ commit }) => {
          return axios.get("/admin/wine_app/shops").then(response => {
            debugger; // I DO have data here??
            commit('updateShop', response.data);
          });
        }
      }
```

But when I stop it with that `debugger` I DO have the data, but when I use the `getShop` action in an component I see the promise being returned.

Any idea why?

EDIT:
It MIGHT just not be ready!! I'm seeing this in the console

```js
    Promise {<pending>}
    __proto__: Promise
    [[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"
    [[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make the action **getShop** async

```
getShop: async ({ commit }) => {
  const response = await axios.get("/admin/wine_app/shops");
  debugger; // I DO have data here??
  commit('updateShop', response.data);
}
```

2. await the action where you call it

```
await this.$store.dispatch('getShop')
```

3. Use the **shop** state prop in your code

```
this.$store.state.shop
```

or use mapState if you would like to use several state props.

Also make sure not to return any data from mutations. They must change state and not return its props.

Comment: nope.. Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (102:6)

Comment: That's why you should make an upper function async as well, Is it possible?

Comment: There's no need to make the `getShop` asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing a promise is because your action is returning the axios call. Remove the `return` in both your mutation and action methods.

Your action method uses axios to retrieve the data. This then commits your mutation with the response data. Your mutation method updates the state with that data. At this point your state.shop is updated.

Within your Vue components you can access that data by accessing the state as a computed property.

```
computed: {
    shop() {
        return this.$store.state.shop
    }

    // Or use mapState
    ...mapState(['shop'])
}
```

Whenever your state changes this should update in your components due to reactivity.